# PHP preg_replace to replace content within specific tags

Tags: php, html

I want to change this:

```
<div>
  <div>
    <div id="myList">
      <table><tr><td></td></tr></table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Into this:

```
<table><tr><td></td></tr></table>
```

What would the preg_replace() be? I have tried the following but to no avail:

```
$result = preg_replace('#<div(.*?)(?! id="myList")>(.*?)</div>#is', '', $result);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [strip_tags](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php)

```
$string = '<div>
  <div>
    <div id="myList">
      <table><tr><td></td></tr></table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>';

echo strip_tags($string, '<table><tr><td>');
```

Comment: Props to you for [avoiding the RegEx pony](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2370483)

Answer (score 1):

@Reado
try this

```
$s='<div>
  <div>
    <div id="myList">
      <table><tr><td></td></tr></table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>';
    $replace=str_replace(array('<div>', '<div id="myList">','</div>'),"",$s);
```